# How to delete a row in mysql?

Tags: mysql, row, sql-delete, delete-row

Is it possible to delete one or more rows from a table in MySql ? I want to delete the last two rows from the following table.

```
+-------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+
| gp_no | no_of_member | amount    | current_instalment | starting_date |
+-------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+
|     1 |           15 | 375000.00 |                  2 | 2015-05-01    |
|     2 |           10 | 300000.00 |                  1 | 2015-07-01    |
|     3 |           15 | 450000.00 |                  5 | 2015-04-01    |
|     4 |           10 | 400000.00 |                  0 | 2015-09-01    |
|     5 |           10 | 400000.00 |                  0 | 2015-07-01    |
+-------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: @naggarwall11...I hope you have got the required solution. But since I find you are finding it bit confusing regarding mysql. I would suggest you try [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog), because it has got a [impressive GUI](http://sqlyogkb.webyog.com/article/161-sqlyog-user-interface),wherein you can delete the rows you need with just few clicks,thus eliminating the need to write queries.   Hope you may find it helpful!!

Comment: Sure @Mathew : I'll try it . Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `gp_no` is primary key and auto-incremented you can delete last 2 records as

```
delete from table_name order by gp_no desc limit 2
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to decide the order of the rows. Assuming your first column is unique;

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE 1 ORDER BY gp_no DESC LIMIT 2
```

But you might also want to expressly delete the last two rows according to date, say the most recent `starting_date`s

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE 1 ORDER BY starting_date DESC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: What is `where 1 `doing here ?

Comment: `Where 1` is telling mysql to consider ALL rows for the sorting. Ullas, yes you're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from table_name order by gp_no desc limit 2
```

Answer is clearly given in comments