# i want to make delete button

Tags: php, mysql

So i start the language in this summer,and i have problem,i don't know how to make delete button,i looked lot of pages but i can't find how to make with pdo.

**countryandcity.php**

```
<?php

    require 'pdo.php';
    $connect=connect();

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">

            <table class="table" >

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Country</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Image</th>
                    </tr>
                    <form action="deleteall.php" method="POST" >

                    <?php
                        $sql = connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY country");
                        $sql->execute();
                        while($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                            echo"<tr>";
                            echo"<td>".$result['country']."</td>";
                            echo"<td>".$result['city']."</td>";
                            if(!empty($result['image'])){
                                echo '<td><img src="images/'.$result['image'].'"/></td>';
                            }

                             else {
                                 echo"<td>-</td>";
                             }

                             echo "<td><a href='edit.php?uid=".$result['country']."'>Edit</a></td>";
                            echo "<td><a href='deleteall.php?uid=".$result['country']."'>Delete</a></td>";

                            echo"</tr>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </form>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

**deleteall.php**

```
<?php

require 'pdo.php';
$connect=connect();
if(isset($_POST['delete_btn']))

    ?><!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>

            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Do u want to delete?</label>
                </div>
                <button>
                    <input type="submit"  value="YES" name="delete_btn">
                </button>
                <button>
                    <input type="submit" name="no" value="NO">

                </button>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Please help me with the sql query and php code after if(isset), i need help!
I just want to delete on row from the database.

How can I solve this?
Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, the SQL query would involve the `DELETE` keyword if you want to delete the record.  Surely a variety of introductory tutorials cover this.  It honestly sounds like you should be starting with some tutorials and getting more of a handle on the basics.

Comment: you want to delete action in details page or in link you want to add delete ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a row in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755253/how-to-delete-a-row-in-mysql)

Comment: Yes,i want to delete one row from database,when i click the delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is correction of your firsts page (content in `<tbody>` instead of `<thead>`, no `<form>` needed, ...) **countryandcity.php** :

```
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>column name...</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

<?php

$sql = connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY country");
$sql->execute();
if($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    foreach($result as $i => $item) {
        extract($item);

        echo "<tr><td>$country</td>";
        echo "<td>$city</td>";

        if(!empty($image)) {
            echo "<td><img src=\"images/$image\"/></td>";
        }

        else {
            echo "<td>-</td>";
        }

        echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?uid=$country\">Edit</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"deleteall.php?uid=$country\">Delete</a></td></tr>";

    }
}

?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here solution for deleting your record in **deleteall.php** :

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['delete_btn'])) {

        $country = addslashes($_GET['delete_btn']);
        $q = "DELETE FROM countries WHERE country = '$country'";

        require 'pdo.php';
        $sql = connect()->prepare($q);
        $sql->execute();
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you, you can add delete link then go this page it will delete

```
<a href="http://localhost/edit.php?uid=22" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Edit</a>
<a href="http://localhost/edit.php?uid=22" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a>

<?php

require 'pdo.php';
$connect = connect();

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

    <table class="table">

        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Image</th>
        </tr>
        <form action="deleteall.php" method="POST">
            <?php
            $sql = connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY country");
            $sql->execute();
            while ($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                if (!empty($result['image'])) {
                    $content_image = '<td><img src="images/' . $result['image'] . '"/></td>';
                } else {
                    $content_image = '<td>-</td>';
                }
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <td> <?= $result['country'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $result['city'] ?></td>
                    <?= $content_image ?>
                    <td><a href="edit.php?uid=<?= $result['country'] ?>">Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a href="deleteall.php?uid=<?= $result['country'] ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            <?php }

            ?>

        </form>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

then this is your deleteall.php

```
  <?php
$uid = trim($_GET['uid']);
if(isset($uid)) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM countries  WHERE country = ?";
    $q = connect()->prepare($sql);

    $response = $q->execute(array($uid));
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks it's help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For the form, I'd recommend having a button that acts as the function, that way you don't accidentally lose all your data when the page loads, or anything like that. This is simply three lines of code.

```
<form action="deleteall.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="true" name="cameFromForm">
    <button type="submit" name="confirmButton">Delete All</button>
</form>
```

When the button is clicked, then it will trigger the entry point of deleteall.php, which then takes the input and deletes ALL data from the table.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST["cameFromForm"]) && $_POST["cameFromForm"] == "true") {  
    // This makes sure that the form actually sent it.
        try {

            $tableName = "Insert the name of your table here";

            $mysqli = new mysqli(
                'databaseHost', 
                'databaseUser', 
                'databasePassword', 
                'databaseName');

            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM ?");
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $tableName);
            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->close();
            $mysqli->close();

            header('Location: http://afterDeltePage.com');

        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            print($e);
            die();
        }
    }
    else {
        header('Location: http://notAuthorisedPage.com');
    }

?>
```

Once you've finished the process, you should send the user to a page with UI. Try to separate the things you need to show the user and your processes. Also, if this is going to be public, you need to make sure that deleteall is not accessible by anyone by URL.

To do that, you need to move your file out of the wwwroot (public_html usually). There are various topics on how to do that.

[PHP Forms](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) information and [PHP MySQLi](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp) information.

Comment: Thanks its's help me a lot!

Comment: I'm glad that's the case! Remember to edit your question to make sure that people can view it in the future and understand and maybe even solve their own problem!

Comment: Okey,thanks,im new in stackoverflow,so i try!

Comment: That's understandable, it can be hard to start out :)